# "maxContains" limit not working for JSON schema

Tags: json, contains, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How do I check if in the following JSON, the property `isCorrect` has value `true`strictly once. Think of it as a multiple choice question with only one answer, so there can be many elements in the array but answer can only be true once in all the elements.

```
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "choice1",
      "isCorrect": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "choice2",
      "isCorrect": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "choice3",
      "isCorrect": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "choice4",
      "isCorrect": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I used `contains`to validate if at least one of the elements satisfies the condition, but it validates even if there are more than 1 elements with `isCorrect`being `true`, so I used `maxContains`but it doesn't work.

My schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://eg.com/schema2.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Example",
  "required": ["answers"],
  "properties": {
    "answers": {
      "type": "array",
      "contains": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "isCorrect": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "enum": [true]
          }
        }
      },
      "maxContains": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "isCorrect": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This instance should not be validated since it has `true` value occurring twice for `isCorrect` and the schema mentions `maxContains` as 1, however it is not working. What am I doing wrong, is the placement of `maxContains` wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minContains` and `maxContains` were added in `draft 2019-09`.
They are not part of `draft-07`, and unknown keywords are ignored.

At the time of writing, draft 2019-09 is quite new, and only has one known implementation.

For now, you'll have to either implement the keyword yourself as an extension (if the library you're using supports such things), or write additional business logic code which happens after JSON Schema validation.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to buy me a coffee to support JSON Schema related work: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/relequestual